# A seven letter word

Tags: word, wordplay

> The 1st, 2nd and 3rd letters spell a very good athlete.
>
> The 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th form an object that can be used in the
>   mountains.
>
> The 4th, 5th and 6th spell a utensil used at school or at work.
>
> And the 5th, 6th and 7th are the same every year.

What is the word we are looking for?

---

Hint :

> This word is not very common nowadays.

---

*The next one is [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38146/another-seven-letter-word).*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> propend = pro + rope + pen + end

Explanation:

> A *pro* is a professional athlete
>  you use *ropes* to climb mountains
>  you use *pens* both in schools and in offices
>  each year *ends* the same (31 of december)

Comment: This has to be it, but I still don't really "get" the explanation for the last word.

Comment: This is it! But maybe add an explanation for each line sir :)

Comment: I've added the explanation!

Comment: Wow... I would have *never* guessed this, well done! 1+.