# Another seven letter word

Tags: word, wordplay

This is the same principle as [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38104/a-seven-letter-word).

> The 1st, 2nd and 3rd letters spell a body part.
>
> The 2nd, 3rd and 4th spell a mean of expression.
>
> You use the 4th, 5th and 6th everyday.
>
> And the 5th, 6th and 7th is an animal.

What is the word we are looking for?

---

*The next one is [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38320/seven-letter-word-it-goes-on).*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Earthen

Explanation:

The 1st, 2nd and 3rd letters spell a body part.

> Ear.

The 2nd, 3rd and 4th spell a mean of expression.

> Art is a means of expression.

You use the 4th, 5th and 6th everyday.

> The word 'the' is used commonly in speech.

And the 5th, 6th and 7th is an animal.

> Hen.

Comment: Fast! The next ones will have to be harder I guess :(