# Seven letter word : it goes on

Tags: word, wordplay

This is the same principle as [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38146/another-seven-letter-word).

*You seemed to enjoy the first ones, so here is another one. This one is in three lines, and the sentences give less direct clues (in my opinion), in order to be a bit more complicated. Let me know if you prefer this way, or the previous one. Or even if you don't like them at all!*

> You can find the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th letters attractive, unappealing or average, but everyone, included you, has one.
>
> The 3rd, 4th and 5th can be seen running company.
>
> And the 5th, 6th and 7th can be taken, shown or cleared.

What is the word we are looking for?

---

*The next one is [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38425/seven-letter-word-the-last-one).*

Comment: Letters 3,4,5 made it too easy. as soon as I laid that down, it made the rest fall easily into place, and this isn't even my kind of puzzle.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is:

> FACE-OFF.
>  Everyone has a face, which can be either attractive or unappealing to various people.
>  A CEO runs a company.
>  "Take off", "show off", and "clear off" are common English phrases.

Comment: You are quick! I was about to answer the same.

Comment: it is an easy puzzle, once you guess face.

Comment: Damn, fast once again! Some feedback? Too easy?

Comment: @IAmInPLS Yeah, a bit too easy, but still enjoyable.

Comment: I think it's difficult for a puzzle of this sort not to be too easy, and I suspect (with no concrete evidence) that the happy region between "too easy" and "too hard" is very narrow. You're giving somewhat-straightforward definitions for short words, and the fundamental difficulty is that there just aren't that many short words to go round.

Comment: Incidentally, my order of solving was different from the ones implied by Jasen and TecBrat: second clue (really only one plausible answer), then third clue (three letters, first one known), then first clue (four letters, two of them known).

Answer (score 3):

I came up with the same answer as Deusovi:

> XXceo
>  face
>  XXXXoff
>  FACEOFF