# Seven letter word : the last one?

Tags: word, wordplay

The previous one can be find [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38320/seven-letter-word-it-goes-on).

*This might be the last one of the series, as I'd like to concentrate on creating more complex puzzles for you.*

> Some people believe the 1st, 2nd and 3rd letters has to be taken right on time.
>
> The 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th can be found in pain.
>
> And the 5th, 6th and 7th is definitely not manly.

What is the word we are looking for?

Comment: But... why is it the last?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is it :

> Teacher

1st, 2nd and 3rd letters forms the word :

> **Tea** , refers to tea time.

3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th letters forms the word :

> **ache** , another word for pain!

and 5th, 6th and 7th forms the word :

> **her** , definitely not manly.

Comment: Yes, this is the one. Good job!